# Printing floats and integers into a file with given format in python

Tags: python, numpy, csv, format, output

I have this simple code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
import csv
import os
import pandas as pd

data=np.loadtxt('lums.dat')
data2=np.loadtxt('all.dat')

shuffle=np.random.shuffle(data[0::1])

with open('data', 'w') as f:
 writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
 writer.writerows(zip(data2[:,0], data2[:,1], data[:,0], data[:,1], data2[:,4], data2[:,5]))
```

The output look like this:

```
42.9356886 1.0 30.91534 1.0 0.899 1.0
43.6177968 1.0 30.76019 1.0 1.5 1.0
42.6341244 1.0 29.26717 0.0 0.61 1.0
```

However, I need the second, fourth and sixth columns to be integers, and I also want to be able to specify the number of digits of the first, third and fifth columns. Is there a simple way to do that?

Edit: The file lums.dat contains:

```
31.2114100 1
33.0060900 1
31.1879700 1
31.1502300 1
30.0178600 1
29.8382100 1
```

The file all.dat contains:

```
42.9356886 1  31.2114100 1  0.89900000 1
43.6177968 1  33.0060900 1  1.50000000 1
42.6341244 1  31.1879700 1  0.61000000 1
42.5828698 1  31.1502300 1  0.69700000 1
42.2789821 1  30.0178600 1  0.26000000 1
41.9161537 1  29.8382100 1  0.21400000 1
```

Comment: `np.savetxt` lets you specify the column formats.

Comment: `loadtxt` split the input lines on space, and converted all values to float.  Are you familiar with the python `%` formatting method?

Comment: Actually not, I am still a beginner on Python. However, the issue has been solved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is, that you can't change the type to int, because the number is internally still an Array, so I used the `dtype`. It is for managing the type inside an `np.array`. The same work for rounding the numbers, where you have to use the numpy function `np.round` of the same reason.

If you don't want to use the numpy function, you first have to change the variable from array to number.

To format a specific number there is the `%`method in python. To specify the number of digit you use `%.6f` for 6 digits. In your case you first have to handle your array format, which I did which a list operation.

```
import numpy as np
import csv

data = np.loadtxt('lums.dat')
data2 = np.loadtxt('all.dat')

shuffle = np.random.shuffle(data[0::1])

with open('data', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
    writer.writerows(zip(np.round(data2[:, 0], 2), np.array(data2[:, 1], dtype=int), np.round(data[:, 0], 2), np.array(data[:, 1], dtype=int), (np.array(["%.8f" % i for i in data2[:, 4]])), np.array(data2[:, 5], dtype=int)))
```

Comment: Actually I already tried something like this, but I get errors: for round() i get 'TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define __round__ method', while for int() 'TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars'. Both errors are due to my data being numpy arrays, I think, but I am new to Python and I do not know how to deal with that.

Comment: Did my solution got an error, if so, can you proved me the error message.

Comment: can you provide your Data, so that I can reproduce your Error

Comment: Sure, you find all the data in the original post. Basically, I want the output file to keep the same format that I have in the original files, with the same spaces/digits etc. for each row.

Comment: @Hypernova I solve it. It was a problem with the datatype between python and Numpy. I will update my answer.

Comment: It's indeed working, thank you a lot! How can I keep the zeros at the end of the numbers? For example, instead of 0.899 I want it to write 0.89900000 (as in the 5th column, first row of all.dat).  With the current format it is truncating zeros at the end of numbers, even if I'm specifying how many digits I want.

Comment: Can you first specify my answer as the answer. I will continue working on that.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't do it yet, I'm new to StackOverflow too.

Comment: @Hypernova Thanks. I just updated my answer and now you can specify your output up to your desired digit, by changing the number after the %.

Comment: Working as intended. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [32]: txt="""42.9356886 1  31.2114100 1  0.89900000 1 
    ...: 43.6177968 1  33.0060900 1  1.50000000 1 
    ...: 42.6341244 1  31.1879700 1  0.61000000 1"""                                                                 
In [33]: data = np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines())                                                                         
In [34]: data                                                                                                        
Out[34]: 
array([[42.9356886,  1.       , 31.21141  ,  1.       ,  0.899    ,
         1.       ],
       [43.6177968,  1.       , 33.00609  ,  1.       ,  1.5      ,
         1.       ],
       [42.6341244,  1.       , 31.18797  ,  1.       ,  0.61     ,
         1.       ]])
```

Write it to file with a specified format:

```
In [37]: np.savetxt('test.csv', data, fmt='%.7f %d %.7f %d %.7f %d')                                                 
In [38]: cat test.csv                                                                                                
42.9356886 1 31.2114100 1 0.8990000 1
43.6177968 1 33.0060900 1 1.5000000 1
42.6341244 1 31.1879700 1 0.6100000 1
```